# Numerical Methods for nth order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know that any nth order ODE can be made into a system of n first order ODEs. I’m also aware that Euler’s method is a primitive way of getting numerical solutions to first order ODEs.

My question is, can we use Euler’s method to “solve” nth order ODE, perhaps by conversion into a system of equations? If so, it would be very enlightening to me if someone could outline how to carry out the procedure as I can’t see how it would be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll let more experienced people answer more thoroughly if necessary, but essentially Euler's method can just be done on the system of first order ODEs by considering it as a single variable first order ODE but in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a vector ODE if you will, and adapted from there.